# I can run elementary on my USB and install on my hard drive but cannot run it from my hard drive

Tags: system-installation

I have installed elementary from USB onto an erased disk. While I can run from the USB and also apparently install it from there it will not load up if I remove the USB. I have a Sony Vaio dual core i7. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it an external hard drive or the one inside the laptop? What kind of message you get when you boot? have you tried going into the firmware (bios) settings and change the first boot option? or also choosing elementary grub from the boot menu (press F12 on boot and it'll show up) ??

Comment: Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu it **should** handle secure boot correctly.  However, if you are working with an older PC, you might want to go to BIOS and disable secure boot and try re-installing.